# Cleanup after upgrade server 13.04 to 13.10

Tags: server, 13.10, services

Still new to ubuntu here and trying to run a server (dhcpd and bind9 for starters). I installed back when 13.04 came out, today I upgraded to 13.10. Because dhcpd and bind9 are my points of interest right now, after upgrade I went to check if they work. First of all I did

```
service --status-all
```

and to my surprise, isc-dhcp-server showed `[-]` (not running) while bind9 showed a `[+]`.
I then entered

```
ps ax | grep dhcpd
```

and got this in response:

```
 2143 ?        Ss     0:00 dhcpd -user dhcpd -group dhcpd -f -q -4 -pf /run/dhcp-server/dhcpd.pid -cf /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf eth0
 2201 pts/0    S+     0:00 grep --color=auto dhcpd
```

and of course I checked syslog to see if it actually leases addresses, and it does. Next thing of interest was, when I looked up possible causes here on askubuntu, I found [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/202224/why-does-service-service-name-status-give-different-responses-for-different-serv) - OP shows his output of commands

```
ls -l /etc/init.d/
ls -l /etc/init
```

and he's got it showing that `dhcpd` is an upstart job, while I got it as normal service without it being upstart:

```
kitet@silica:~$ ls -l /etc/init.d | grep dhcp
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 2799 Aug 27 00:24 isc-dhcp-server
```

I also checked what files currently are installed by isc-dhcp-server and got this in response:

```
kitet@silica:~$ dpkg -L isc-dhcp-server
/.
/usr
/usr/sbin
/usr/sbin/dhcpd
/usr/share
/usr/share/man
/usr/share/man/man8
/usr/share/man/man8/dhcpd.8.gz
/usr/share/man/man5
/usr/share/man/man5/dhcpd.conf.5.gz
/usr/share/man/man5/dhcpd.leases.5.gz
/usr/share/lintian
/usr/share/lintian/overrides
/usr/share/lintian/overrides/isc-dhcp-server
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/isc-dhcp-server
/usr/share/doc/isc-dhcp-server/examples
/usr/share/doc/isc-dhcp-server/examples/dhcpd.conf
/usr/share/doc/isc-dhcp-server/copyright
/usr/share/doc/isc-dhcp-server/NEWS.Debian.gz
/usr/share/apport
/usr/share/apport/package-hooks
/usr/share/apport/package-hooks/isc-dhcp-server.py
/etc
/etc/dhcp
/etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf
/etc/apparmor.d
/etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.dhcpd
/etc/apparmor.d/dhcpd.d
/etc/init
/etc/init/isc-dhcp-server6.conf
/etc/init/isc-dhcp-server.conf
/etc/init.d
/etc/init.d/isc-dhcp-server
/var
/var/run
/var/lib
/var/lib/dhcp
/usr/share/doc/isc-dhcp-server/README.Debian
/usr/share/doc/isc-dhcp-server/changelog.Debian.gz
```

There's a file `/etc/init/isc-dhcp-server.conf` which LOOKS like an upstart job config, because it has `start on` and `stop on` in it. There also is `/etc/init.d/isc-dhcp-server` which is what?

**Question:** What does it all mean? Do I actually have two of them? one being a stopped service and one an upstart job? Do I need to clean up something after upgrade? Sorry about these Q's, I'm still trying to grasp where are all the files are located.

Answer (score 2):

My noobish 2 cents :

The isc-dhcp-server service can be used to start and stop dhcpd with the right parameters.

Files used :
/etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf
/run/dhcp-server/dhcpd.pid
/etc/default/isc-dhcp-server (be sure to set NICs here)

After the upgrade from 13.04 to 13.10 I had to reboot before the 'service isc-dhcp-server stop' command would function.
I assume that's some kind of flaw, since it's not just me.

Some commands that gave me more questions than answers :

Before reboot, after upgrade to 13.10

```
root@dhcp:~# service --status-all | grep dhcp
 [ - ]  isc-dhcp-server
 [ ? ]  udhcpd

root@dhcp:~# ps -AF | grep dhcp
dhcpd     1196     1  0  6216  7068   0 14:20 ?        00:00:00 dhcpd -user dhcpd -group dhcpd -f -q -4 -pf /run/dhcp-server/dhcpd.pid -cf /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf
root      2270   888  0  2362   896   0 16:57 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto dhcp

root@dhcp:~# service isc-dhcp-server stop
stop: Unknown instance:

root@dhcp:~# service isc-dhcp-server restart
stop: Unknown instance:
isc-dhcp-server start/running, process 1753
```

Multiple times 'service isc-dhcp-server restart' gave me the same stop: Unknown instance message.

After reboot :

```
root@dhcp:~# ps -AF | grep dhcp
avahi      430     1  0  8089  1700   0 16:59 ?        00:00:00 avahi-daemon: running [dhcp.local]
dhcpd      777     1  0  5171  7636   0 17:00 ?        00:00:00 dhcpd -user dhcpd -group dhcpd -f -q -4 -pf /run/dhcp-server/dhcpd.pid -cf /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf eth0 eth1 bond0
root      1314   931  0  2363   896   0 17:00 pts/1    00:00:00 grep --color=auto dhcp

root@dhcp:~# service isc-dhcp-server restart
isc-dhcp-server stop/waiting
isc-dhcp-server start/running, process 1515
```

... and no change to

```
root@dhcp:~# service --status-all | grep dhcp
```

[ - ] for isc-dhcp-server and [ ? ] for udhcpd

Before and after reboot, dhcp was and is up & running.
Something seems off.